# Dump / read NAND from iPhone with checkra1n/checkm8

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I have an old iPhone 5s laying around for years. The phone is getting to boot logo loop infinity. I forgot to backup some extremely important data inside. It was one of my biggest regret, until checkm8 exploit comes out. Since the reason the phone won’t boot is because the HFS+ partition was seriously corrupted(it is jailbreaked, fsck shows many error when it was still alive, experienced similar things a lot on Mac, like b-tree shits). I assume my (at least part of) data and bootrom are still fine. And as I was using the phone right before the moment it dies, I definitely know the passcode.
If my assumption is correct, is it possible to dump the NAND or read files via checkra1n/checkm8?

Appreciation for any help!